# Exception during list comprehension. Are intermediate results kept anywhere?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When using try-except in a for loop context, the commands executed so far are obviously done with

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 'text', 5]

b = []
try:
    for k in range(len(a)):
        b.append(a[k] + 4)
except:
    print('Error!')
print(b)
```

results with

```
Error!
[5, 6, 7]
```

However the same is not true for list comprehensions

```
c=[]
try:
    c = [a[k] + 4 for k in range(len(a))]
except:
    print('Error!')
print(c)
```

And the result is

```
Error!
[]
```

Is the intermediate list, built before the exception occurred, kept anywhere? Is it accessible?

Comment: The values are probably still *in memory* somewhere, but since the assignment to `c` failed (because the creation of the value failed), you don't have any handle on that memory. Your `try` clause failed, you can't expect anything within it to exist. In the first case at least `b` was constructed outside `try`, so is guaranteed to exist. – I'm trying to say: you *shouldn't* want this.

Comment: BTW, why not `[i + 4 for i in a]`...?!

Comment: If you want comprehension-like syntax with the exception-related semantics of your `for` loop with the repeated `append` calls, using `list.extend` with a generator expression might do the trick: `b.extend(a[k] + 4 for k in range(len(a)))`

Comment: @Blckknght nice trick, but please, never do that in real code...

Comment: @Blckknght, Thanks. You probably mean `b.append`? As `extend` will work differently.

Comment: No, I did mean `extend`. The statement I suggested should replace the whole `for` loop, not just your `append` call. By passing it a generator expression, you get the same effect as the explicit loop code (the first results produced by the generator get added to the list, stopping when the exception occurs).

Comment: In CPython, the partially built list will be garbage-collected as soon as its reference count drops to 0.  I expect that this could happen before execution of your exception block, as I can see no reason for it not to.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The list comprehension intermediate results are kept on an internal CPython stack, and are not accessible from the Python expressions that are part of the list comprehension.

Note that Python executes the `[.....]` **first**, which produces a list object, and only **then** assigns that result to the name `c`. If an exception occurs within the `[....]` expression, the expression is terminated and exception handling kicks in instead. Your `print(c)` expression thus can only ever show the *previous* object that `c` was bound to, which here is an empty list object. It could have been anything else:

```
>>> c = 'Anything else'
>>> try:
...     c = [2 // i for i in (1, 0)]
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     pass
...
>>> c
'Anything else'
```

In your first example, no new list object is produced. You instead manipulate (using `b.append()`) an *existing* list object, which is why you can see what all successful `b.append()` calls have done to it.

Answer (score 11):

Let's look at the bytecode:

```
>>> def example():
...     c=[]
...     try:
...         c = [a[k] + 4 for k in range(len(a))]
...     except:
...         print('Error!')
...     print(c)
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(example)

--- removed some instructions       

             27 GET_ITER            
        >>   28 FOR_ITER                20 (to 51)
             31 STORE_FAST               1 (k)
             34 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (a)
             37 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
             40 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             41 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
             44 BINARY_ADD          
             45 LIST_APPEND              2
             48 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           28
        >>   51 STORE_FAST               0 (c)

 --- more instructions...
```

As you can see, the list comprehension is translated to a series of instructions `GET_ITER`...`JUMP_ABSOLUTE`.  The next instruction `STORE_FAST` is the one that modifies `c`. If any exception occurs before it, `c` will not have been modified.